# Akka concurrent message proccesing by preserving the messages order

Tags: concurrency, queue, jms, akka

In our project, we publish and consume messages to/from a JMS broker. We have a PL/SOL producer and a Java consumer. The problem is however; he producer is 10 times faster than the consumer. Theofore we want to change the consumerr to work with multiple threads while reading and processing the messages.

But we need to preserve the order of the messages as well. That said, the messages shall be sent to the target system in the order they were published to the jms broker. I'm new to Akka and i'm trying to understand its features. Can we achieve that using akka dispatchers ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to parallelize the consumption inside a single instance of JVM, what you describe is a good case for [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-index.html). This can be solved with the Actors, but you risk of running out of memory if the producer is too fast, because you'll need to queue the results for re-ordering.

Akka Streams handle this problem with the introduction of backpressure. If consumer can't keep up with the producer, it will indicate this, and producer will reduce the rate. Akka Streams also can maintain the order of the messages.

Akka Streams is a 1.0 software, so it's not yet as battle-hardened as pure Akka, but it's based on Akka and is coming from the Akka team, so it should be good and become even better in the future. Also the documentation is not organized in the best way possible yet.

It's also important to mention that Akka Streams, while implemented using Akka, is quite different paradigm than Actor Model or Future combinations. It's based on stream processing paradigm, so you'll have to adjust the way you think about your programs. Might be an issue for some teams.

Comment: so you think this can not be implemented with pure Akka. I got the impression that it can be implemented with UnboundedPriorityMailbox Dispatcher, but as I said, I'm newbie to Akka and I'm not sure. Can you share some piece of code, or can you elaborate your answer a little bit, so that I can search on specific concepts/topics in order to not go over the whole AkkaStreams documentation in a very limited time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, it can totally be implemented in pure Akka, but, as I said, you're risking running into the OOM exception with unbounded mailboxes. To avoid that, you either has to manually implement the backpressure, or just take the library where it's already implemented, like Akka Streams.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Haspemulator. I would really appreciate it, if you can share some sample code, both for Akka and Akka Streams to get some idea. I'm really lost in the whole documentation.

Comment: do you have some sample code, that you can share with me? Or can you refer to some specific tutorials ? @Haspemulator

Comment: I don't have a code example that's suitable for your particular problem, but have a look at the Streams Cookbook. It covers several topics that might be of interest for you: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M1/scala/stream-cookbook.html. Particularly, pay attention to usage of `mapAsync` function, which allows asynchronous processing of messages while maintaining their original order.